# Ошибка при освобождении памяти (матрица): access violation

Tags: память, c++

Освобождаю память матрицы:

```
   ....
   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   delete [] matrix[i]; //освобождаем из памати все одномерные массивы
 delete [] matrix;   //освоождаем место "главного" массива
 ....
```

и вылетает ошибка на второй итерации в строке: `delete [] matrix[i];`
`access violation`
В чём дело?
Вообще задача: Среди столбцов  целочисленной  матрицы  А(n,m) найти столбец с минимальным произведением элементов.

Сам код:

```
    #include <iostream>
      #include <conio.h>
     #include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  int **matrix;
  int n,m,i,j,min,tmp=1,tmp2, nomerstolbca;
  bool flag=1,flag2=1;
  int *P,*Q;
  cout<<"Enter 1-st size: ";
  cin>>n;
  P=new int[m];
  cout<<"Enter 2-nd size: ";
  cin>>m;
  matrix=new int*[n];  //сюда будут сливаться адреса первых ячеек одномерных массивов
      for(i=0;i<n;i++){
      matrix[i]=new int[m];//одновременно выделяем место и присваиваем ссылку на первый элемент этого массива
          for(j=0;j<m;j++){
          matrix[i][j]=rand()%5+1; //заполняем рандомом от 0 до 5
          cout<<matrix[i][j]<<" "; //на экран
          }
      cout<<endl;
      }

for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
tmp=1;
   for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
   tmp=tmp*matrix[j] [i];
   }
   if (flag) {
     min=tmp;
     nomerstolbca=i+1;
     flag=0;
   }

   if (tmp<min) {
     min=tmp;
     nomerstolbca=i+1;
     }
   P[i]=tmp;
   cout<<endl;
   cout<<P[i];

}
cout<<"Stolbec s minimanym kol-vom elementov " <<nomerstolbca<<endl;
//проверка столбцов с одинаковым произведением
for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
  if ((P[i]==min) && (i!=nomerstolbca)) {
     if (flag2) {
      cout<<"Nomera stolbcov s odinakovymy proizvedenyami: ";
     flag2=0;
     }
     cout<<i+1;
  }
}

delete []P; //очищаем память вспомогательного массива

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   delete [] matrix[i]; //освобождаем из памати все одномерные массивы
delete [] matrix;   //освоождаем место "главного" массива
getch();//стопорит консоль
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Если вы пишете на C++, то стоит использовать контейнеры вместо Си-массивов, например, std::vector Это избавит вас от головной боли, связанной с выделением/освобождением памяти.
Кстати, если вам нужна матричная арифметика, то стоит посмотреть в сторону библиотеки uBLAS: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
P=new int[m];
cout<<"Enter 2-nd size: ";
cin>>m;
```

Переменная m используется до инициализации, может быть дело в этом.

---

Не понятно почему так сложно запустить программу под дебагером и посмотреть что происходит.

Comment: >Не понятно почему так сложно запустить программу под дебагером и посмотреть что происходит

а зачем, когда есть желающие ее подебажить за ТСа?

Comment: http://i076.radikal.ru/1309/3b/34cab5c7b37f.png скриншот ошибки

Comment: @Fogbit, думаю Вы правы. 

Видимо еще не инициализированная  m при выполнении 

     P=new int[m];

в самом деле мала, и последующее присваивание

    P[i]=tmp;

портит структуры аллокатора памяти, что и приводит к фатальной ошибке в delete [].

@Fogbit, скорее я рассказываю это автору вопроса (чтобы ему было понятней), а не Вам.

Кстати, лучший дебагер - это голова (ну и печать в нужных точках программы ей в помощь).